# Making a CSS animation work on Mozilla

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-animations

So I have a set of images here is the HTML for them :

```
<figure>
    <img src="">
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/192/96/sports/2" alt="Portfolio Item">
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="">
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="">
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="">
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="">
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/192/96/sports/7" alt="Portfolio Item">
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="">
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="">
    <figcaption>
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

They look like boxes and when you click on then a CSS animation is triggered and they flip one side has an image the other has text, here is the CSS code:

```
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 0%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 50%,
                      hsla(0,0%,0%,.015) 50%, hsla(0,0%,0%,.015) 100%),
                      -webkit-radial-gradient(hsla(0,0%,0%,.05) 10%, transparent 15%);
    background-size: 1.5em 1.5em, .5em .5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1.5em;
    width: 45em;
}
figure {
    float: left;
    height: 6em;
    margin: 1.5em;
    width: 12em;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500) rotateX(90deg) translateY(-3em) translateZ(3em);
}
img {
    background-color: #222;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px -10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover img {
    box-shadow: none;
}
figcaption {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1.5em;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px -10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
}
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}​
```

Everything works perfectly fine, but when you open it through Mozilla the animation dosen't work and I don't know why I am using the webkit prefix and still it dosen't work on Mozilla how can I make it work there as well

Comment: Because mozilla uses -moz as prefix not -webkit. Try to use -moz prefix.

Comment: Mozilla added support for -webkit in 2016. You're not wrong. At least that's what I thought first.

Answer (score 0):

The `perspective()` CSS function's parameter uses units of length.
Change `perspective(500)` to `perspective(500px)` to make it work on Firefox and Edge.

Also, prefixes are now used for supporting old browser versions. Firefox uses the `-moz-` prefix. Newer versions of majors browser are stopping the use of vendor prefixes for compatibility. You should use animations properties with and without prefixes to support most browsers.

```
body {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .015) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .015) 100%),
                        linear-gradient(left, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .015) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .015) 100%),
                        -webkit-radial-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .05) 10%, transparent 15%), 
                        radial-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .05) 10%, transparent 15%);
    background-size: 1.5em 1.5em, .5em .5em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1.5em;
    width: 45em;
}
figure {
    float: left;
    height: 6em;
    margin: 1.5em;
    width: 12em;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500px);
    -moz-transform: perspective(500px);
    transform: perspective(500px);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-3em) translateZ(3em);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-3em) translateZ(3em);
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-3em) translateZ(3em);
}
img {
    background-color: #222;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px -10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .25);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover img {
    box-shadow: none;
}
figcaption {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1.5em;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px -10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .25);
}
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
​
```

Mozilla Developer Network has more info on [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/perspective) and [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

Hope this helps.